# If Anakin brought balance to the Force, how could Kylo Ren be trained in the dark side?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, kylo-ren

In one of the prequels Yoda says to Obi-Wan after Anakin kills the “dark apprentice” there is always two a Sith and an apprentice. Only two no more no less. So fast forward to Darth Vader’s death. When Darth Vader kills the Sith Lord and in turn dies himself that should be the end of the “dark side”. So in retrospect where did the new Sith “big creepy hologram guy” come from?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking. Is your question about who Snoke is? Or how Snoke can exist if Anakin brought balance to the Force? It’s a duplicate either way, but the question is which.

Comment: I edited your title to focus on what I think your question is. Feel free to rollback or edit if I made a mistake.

Comment: The new guy isn't a Sith.

Comment: It was my belief that aniken destroyed the dark side so I guess if I had to narrow it to 1 question it would be if the sith and darth vader die. How is there still a dark side? Like I said Yoda explained 1 sith 1 appreciate no more no less.

Comment: @RichardSpence - All right, so it looks like I was right about what you were asking, and the question I marked as duplicate does answer that question.

Comment: Anakin didn't destroy the dark side, bringing balance to the Force was conceived by Lucas specifically in terms of destroying the Sith, who seem to have been unbalancing the Force in favor of the dark side, suggesting that destroying them would restore a balance between light and dark. See [the "Behind the scenes" section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One/Legends#Behind_the_scenes) of the Chosen One article on wookieepedia for details.